# Cassandra - combining multiple tables as a view

Tags: cassandra, triggers, cassandra-3.0, materialized-views

I have 20 tables in Cassandra. For one particular request, I need data from all 20 tables. How can I do this? Can I use a materialized view in Cassandra?

Or should I use Cassandra trigger and make an entry in different table whenever something changes in any of the 20 tables?

Or is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The materialized view in Cassandra just maintaining a new table based on the data of the single table, so you can't use this functionality for your purpose. Triggers are also not designed for this kind of work.

So for you, the only the choice is to do a multiple requests to many tables (slow), or maintain a separate table with all data that are necessary for answering this query - this is recommended way in Cassandra, as all table structures are based on the queries.

I recommend to take DS220 course on Data modeling on [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/)

Comment: Thanks, @Alex Ott for the quick reply. Actually, I already have an application, that is doing multiple async and concurrent calls to Cassandra. Because these are async and concurrent calls, they are taking 10ms to 20ms on average for all Cassandra calls. Is it still worth taking efforts, to maintain separate table and sync every time anything changes or add in those 20 tables and migrate old data in it?
That’s why I was thinking if we have something in Cassandra which can make this thing simpler for me, without changing my code.

Comment: thanks for DS220 recommendation. The course is awesome!!!